# How to use dynamic variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamically-generated

I have a dynamically created variable called `item_908` (where 908 is dynamically).
Later on, there is a variable called `id`, which holds the string `"908"`.

Now, i need to access the variable `item_908` programmatically and i cannot remember how to do it. Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: Just don't do dynamic variables. Use a friggin' array. Or if it's more than a number, an object. But don't pollute scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are in the global scope:

```
window["item_" + id];
```

else you can only access them throu an Object:

```
var obj = {},
    id = 908;

obj.item_908 = "abc";


obj["item_" + id]; // abc
```

Answer (score 1):

You may access it by using:

```
window['item_908'];
```